# SQL stored procedure OUT always returning Null

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to create a login in SQL and using stored procedures to capture the login information.

Even when executing the stored procedure on phpmyadmin, my out param is always returning Null, and I can't figure out why.

`userid` is my OUT param, I am getting back an email and password and the rest of the fields are empty strings.

```
BEGIN
set @userid = (select id from `user` where `email` = email and `password` = password and statusId = 8);

if @userid is not null
then
    set @statu = 9;
elseif @userid is null
then
    set @statu = 10;
end if;

call loginHistory(@userid, email, @statu, ip4, ip6, deviceType, appVer);

set @userid = userid;
END
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have so many clauses in your WHERE statement? If your email is unique then basically you just need to select id from user where email = email.

Comment: You're right, the email is unique so there was no need for any of the rest. 
I haven't done SQL for years so still a learning process :). 
The issue that userid is null is still happening though

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with phpmyadmin syntax, but the SQL statement would be SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = 'nash@stackoverflow.com'; And thats if your table columns are labeled id and email. Is your table called user or users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
set @userid = userid;
```

to

```
SET userid = @userid;
```

`userid` and `@userid` are different things.

If that does not suffice, show us the rest of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your parameters.  Name them with a prefix, such as `in`.

So I think you want:

```
BEGIN
   select @user_id := u.id
   from `user`u
    where u.email = in_email and
          u.password = in_password and
          u.statusId = 8;

    set @statu = (case when @userid is not null then 9 else 10 end);

    call loginHistory(@userid, in_email, @statu, in_ip4, in_ip6, in_deviceType, in_appVer);

    set @userid = in_userid;
END;
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but at least the code will do something more sensible.

Comment: If the in_userid is the OUT-parameter, the @userid should probably be omitted and to use in_userid. Also, it's better to use local variables (DECLARE v_var...) inside the procedure rather than user defined parameters (@var) as the values for user defined parameters can change when one calls other routines (like loginHistory),